# Where does it say In Shulchan Aruch That Grains don’t need to be checked so much?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization, bugs, yoreh-deah, chulin-tractate

BH

I’m trying to check Grains in order to make flour and someone told me that grains them selfs don’t need to be checked so much and could possibly fall into the same category as Oranges which I heard arn’t so common to get infested. Does it say this in Shulchan Aruch? Where does it talk about in Halacha how much you need to check grains before you make them into flour?

Comment: Basically the need to  check depends on how common it is for there to be a bug problem, which depends on species, location, and time period. Modern Kashrus agencies are the ones who do the checking. What it says in Shulchan Aruch can give you general principles, but not whether wheat grown in the southwest U.S. needs checking this year.